# Duplicating every row in dataframe N times where N is random

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set like so:

**Input:**

```
id name
1  tim
2  jim
3  john
4  bill
```

I want to duplicate each row in my data set randomly anywhere from 0 - 5 times.

So my final data set might look something like this:

**Output:**

```
id name
1  tim
1  tim
2  jim
3  john
3  john
3  john
3  john
4  bill
4  bill
4  bill
```

how can i do this in python pandas?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a random array of repeats with [`numpy.uniform`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) and use that to [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) your index for indexing:

```
out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(np.random.uniform(0, 5+1, size=len(df)))]
```

Example:

```
   id  name
0   1   tim
0   1   tim
0   1   tim
0   1   tim
0   1   tim
1   2   jim
1   2   jim
2   3  john
3   4  bill
3   4  bill
3   4  bill
3   4  bill
```

Output with `np.random.seed(42)`:

```
   id  name
0   1   tim
0   1   tim
1   2   jim
1   2   jim
1   2   jim
1   2   jim
1   2   jim
2   3  john
2   3  john
2   3  john
2   3  john
3   4  bill
3   4  bill
3   4  bill
```

Comment: Great! How come when I set np.random.seed(42) and run it multiple times it doesn't create the same data frame?

Comment: @Eisen do you run again `np.random.seed(42)` before each run? If not the random number generator has moved to a different step ;)

Comment: running `np.random.seed(42)` before 
`out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(np.random.uniform(0, 5+1, size=len(df)))]` in the same cell produces different results for me

Comment: Is your output with this code the same as mine above (the second one)?

Comment: Each time, you use `np.random.<function>` you have to set the seed again.